# how to escape the pipe character ("|") in yaml files as key?

Tags: yaml, pipe, escaping, character

Is there an explicit way to escape the | character in yaml files?
I don't want to use the pipe literal, but the character itself.

I tried the following yaml:
"A||B": "ASCENDING"

Tried also:
"A\|\|B": "ASCENDING"

but when reading the yaml I see:
"AB": "ASCENDING"

Comment: Not reproducible. The `|` character is always loaded literally as long as it is not a value by itself.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned I used java snake yaml parser. maybe it is related to this specific parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap it with the square brackets `"[A||B]"`